# Get latest record for each ID in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of the form:

```
id | date | metric1 | metric2 ... | metricN
```

I want to get the all latest metrics for each `id`? I can use the GROUPBY function and the MAX(date) to get the latest date, and then join with the table to get the correct row, but is there a more efficient way to do this in MS SQL server (perhaps with some sort of RANK query)?

Comment: Did you try anything using `RANK` window function.

Comment: If this is the first/original table in the query, the MAX()/JOIN combo is how I currently do it. If the table is itself added to the query via join, you can use an APPLY operator instead to combine the steps. But I'd also love to know a better way.